# How to access elements of 2D array created with malloc, using pointers?

Tags: c

I have code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int x=10;
int y=10;

int **data = (int**) malloc(x * sizeof(int));
if(!**data){
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
}
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    *(data+i) = (int*) malloc(y * sizeof(int));
    if(!*(data+i)){
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
        data[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
        printf("%3i ",data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


return 0;
}
```

How can i access points of that array using pointers instead of `data[i][j]`?

I tried searching for answer but in every example I see people use `data[x][y]` option, i have to use pointers for accessing each element.

Also is error handling correct in that code?

```
if(!**data){
    printf("Error");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: No, the error handling code is not correct. Do `if (! data) {}`.

Comment: Since `int ** data` *defines a **pointer***, doing `data[x][y]` ***is*** using pointers.

Comment: In C there is no need to cast from/to `void`-pointers. Just drop the cast to `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a major problem, especially on 64-bit systems where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`:

```
int **data = (int**) malloc(x * sizeof(int));
```

You allocate `x` times the size of `int`, not the size of pointer to `int`.

There is a good "trick" to always get the correct size, use `sizeof *variable_youre_allocating_for`. In your case it would be

```
int **data = malloc(x * sizeof *data);
```

This works because `sizeof *data` is done at compile-time, and the compiler knows that `*data` is of type `int *` and will use the correct size.

Also notice that I removed the cast, [it's not needed in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Besides that, your use of the data is correct. Using `data[i][j]` is perfectly fine, if `i` and `j` are valid indexes, and `data` and `data[i]` have been properly initialized.

The important part is to remember that for any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`. In fact, the compiler will translate `a[i]` to `*(a + i)`. So for your pointer `data`, the expression `*(data + i)` is exactly equal to `data[i]`. And the latter is usually easier to read and understand, as well as less to write.

Comment: Thanks for those hints, i really appreciate them, but it still isn't answer for my question, how to acces elements of newly created array using pointers.

Comment: I actually figured out that i can do it by: *(*(data+i)+j).

Comment: @PatrykKorczak Please don't write that! It's exactly equal to `data[i][j]`, but more to write and harder to read. Updated answer.

Comment: I'd love to just do it this way, but my exercise requires that. I'm forced to  use pointers.

Comment: @PatrykKorczak Even with `data[i][j]` you are *still* using pointers, as both `data` and `data[i]` *are* pointers.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that. My fault. I cant use [ ] in my code.